# Word usage of raise

Tags: word-usage

If I say the sentence below 
1. Does it sound unnatural 
2. Or gramatically wrong ?
3. Or does it have the different meaning 
From the second  sentence? If so will please kindly explain to me please?

I was glad to see the tree that I **had raised** for years

I was glad to see the tree that I **had grown** for years

Comment: Hello, 515. Do senses 12 and 13 given by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/raise) suggest that 'raise' would be used for an individual tree? (Even the use of 'grown for years' is questionable; who grew it after you'd stopped? Though using 'I grew a tree in the back garden' without an implied end-point / change of nurturer is idiomatic.)

Comment: *I was glad to see the tree that I had raised for years* is fine but use of it would be fairly obscure…